# Http.Post in Vue.js with Object not posting correct data

Tags: http, vue.js, asp.net-core-mvc

I had a Vue.js App as below

```
    var vueCommentApp = new Vue({
            el: '#Commentdiv',           
            data: {
                 newComment:{"userCommentID":0,"siteurlID":1,"userId":"","userName":"Guest","commentPageType":"","commentDesc":null,"parentUserCommentID":null,"islast":false,"isApproved":false,"isActive":false,"addedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"}                
                  }
            ,
            methods: {          
                SaveComment: function () {
                     this.$http.post('/Comment/AddComment', this.newComment ).then(result => {                   
                       //Success 
                    }, error => {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

And my Html looks like below

```
<div id="Commentdiv">
                <p>                    
                    <input id="Email" placeholder="Write your Email here!" type="email" class="form-control " v-model.lazy="newComment.userId" />
                </p>
                <p>                  
                    <input id="UserName" placeholder="Write your name here!" type="text" class="form-control " v-model.lazy="newComment.userName" />
                </p>
                <p>                   
                    <textarea id="Comment" placeholder="Write your comment here!" class="pb-cmnt-textarea form-control" v-model.lazy="newComment.commentDesc"></textarea>
                </p>
                <p><button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" v-on:click="SaveComment" type="button">Share</button></p>
</div>
```

When user hits the Share button Savecomment Function is executed and the API call is made .But the API is not getting the data entered by user instead default values are filled

```
      [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddComment(UserCommentVm newComment)
        {
            //return Json(this.commentRepository.AddComment(NewComment));
            return Json("");
        }
```

And my Viewmodal is exactly same as from view

```
 public class UserCommentVm
    {      
        public int userCommentID { get; set; }
        public int siteurlID { get; set; }    
        public String userId { get; set; }    
        public String userName { get; set; }    
        public String commentPageType { get; set; }
        public String commentDesc { get; set; }    
        public int? parentUserCommentID { get; set; }    
        public Boolean islast { get; set; }    
        public Boolean isApproved { get; set; }    
        public Boolean isActive { get; set; }    
        public DateTime addedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

[image: Please see the image for More details]

Comment: Can you just try using only v-model instead of v-model.lazy. using lazy will only update original value on change event. And also console userComment in saveComment method and check the values.

Comment: Already removed lazy..also console.log(JSON.stingify(newcomment)) gives {"userCommentID":0,"siteurlID":1,"userId":"Sreeath.sreeganga@gmail.com","userName":"Sreeath.sreeganga","commentPageType":"Question","commentDesc":null,"parentUserCommentID":null,"islast":false,"isApproved":false,"isActive":false,"addedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"}

Comment: What is `this.$http`?  Are you using `vue-resource`?  Do you have this same problem if you use `Axios` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I issue was with $http.post in vue.resources (not sure what it is)  converted it to Axios and its now working

```
 SaveComment: function () {        
            axios({
                url: '/Comment/AddComment',
                method: 'post',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data:   this.newComment,  
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                }).catch(error => {
 console.log(error);
                });            
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{"userCommentID":0,"siteurlID":1,"userId":"Sreeath.sreeganga@gmail.com","userName":"Sreeath.sreeganga","commentPageType":"Question","commentDesc":null,"parentUserCommentID":null,"islast":false,"isApproved":false,"isActive":false,"addedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"}
```

As i see in this response your values are already updated for keys where you have used v-model. (email, name)

As you have not updated values for other keys default values are being passed.

Please note that v-model will just update the value of keys of your original object **newComment** and hence the values that are set by default will be set as default if not updated while passing to the api.

Comment: I know these values are set at client side..sorry that i didnt clearly mentioned values not updating correctly in serverside action..Please see the image